# About default and copy constructors

Tags: c++, inheritance, copy-constructor

Consider the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

struct A
{
    A() {} // Can't be commented
    A( const A& other ) =delete;
    int i;
};

struct B : public A
{
    B( int j ) { this->i = j; }
    B( const B& other ) { this->i = other.i; }
};

int main()
{
    B b(42);
    std::cout << b.i << std::endl;
}
```

Why can't I compile this code if I comment the empty constructor of A? I thought A always had a default constructor, what changes when I disable its copy constructor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have declared at least one non-default constructor, the compiler will not generate a default constructor for you. This actually makes sense if you think a bit. Imagine a class that can be created without some values being passed to the constructor. In this case even you would not be able to create empty constructor, no matter how much you try.

When you comment out the empty constructor of A, the constructors of B will not be able to call it.

When you comment out both constructors, then the compiler considers it OK to generate default implementations for the copy and empty constructors.

Comment: But does the deletion of a constructor count as a definition??

Comment: @LuchianGrigore yes you are right. I have corrected this statement.

Comment: @Sh3ljohn as pointed out by juanchopanza below and by my answer above the problem is in fact that the constructors of B implicitly call the default constructor of A.

Comment: @Sh3ljohn: It counts as a declaration. The terminology in this answer is a bit wonky - you only need to *declare* (not define) a constructor to inhibit the implicit default constructor.

Answer (score 5):

Because this constructor:

```
B( int j ) { this->i = j; }
```

is default-initializing `B`'s `A` sub-object. It is doing the equivalent of this:

```
B( int j ) : A() { this->i = j; }
```

Since `A` has a user-declared non-default constructor (even if it is declared as `deleted`), the compiler does not synthesize a default constructor for you. So you need to provide it yourself.

Comment: I wasn't the one to downvote, sorry about that. This doesn't really answer my question though; if I comment both constructors in A, then I can compile.. Hence my question "what changes when I disable its copy constructor"?

Comment: I personally think your answer is good and also see no reason for the downvote.

Answer (score 1):

As soon as you declare a constructor in a class (and a deleted one is declared, he is just ... deleted), the compiler will no longer generate any default constructor for you.

So if you comment out the default constructor, you don't have any constructor left for the class A that can be use by B's constructors (because B's constructor is doing a *default init* of the A part inside B). And it can't call A's default constructor (because there is none !) and the code is ill-formed.

Comment: "As soon as you declare a constructor in a class (and a deleted one is declared, he is just ... deleted), the compiler will not generate any other constructor for you." - wrong.

Comment: Indeed, there is the move constructor. I forgot default